# pipenv insists on installing Python 3.6

Tags: python, pipenv, pyenv

I set up my Python dev environment on macOS using the following commands:

```
brew install pyenv
pyenv install 3.7.0
pyenv install 2.7.15
pyenv global 3.7.0
```

I also added the following to my `.bash_profile`:

```
export PATH="/Users/me/.local/bin:$PATH"
eval "$(pyenv init -)"
```

Python seems to be working as expected:

```
01:29 $ python --version
Python 3.7.0
```

I then installed pipenv the "[pragmatic](https://pipenv.readthedocs.io/en/latest/install/#pragmatic-installation-of-pipenv)" way, since installing via Homebrew would install a whole copy of Python as well (which I didn't want, since I was using pyenv already):

```
pip install --user pipenv
```

Now when I try to start a new pipenv project I get the following message:

```
01:28 $ mkdir my-new-project && cd my-new-project && pipenv install
Warning: Python 3.6 was not found on your system...
Would you like us to install CPython 3.6.6 with pyenv? [Y/n]:
```

I thought pipenv automatically used whatever pyenv copy of Python was available -- which is 3.7.0 in my case. Where is the prompt about installing CPython 3.6.6 coming from?

Comment: What's in your `Pipfile`?

Comment: @kichik I don’t have one, I’m running `pipenv install` to generate one. I thought it would automatically use whatever `pyenv global` was set to. Is that not true?

Comment: I don't know about that, but you can always tell it which version to use with `pipenv --python 3.6`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Short answer: if you're seeing weird behavior like this, run `pipenv --support` and read carefully.

I had a stray `Pipfile` that was hanging out in the *parent directory* of my project that was dictating the version of Python to install. I'm guessing there's some sort of recursive search during `pipenv install` that looks for a `Pipfile` in any directory outside the current one.